# Android Opengl boundries

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm developing a 3D game for android and I was wondering if it's possible to get a bounding box in opengl. Basically, I'm using the accelerometer to control an object and I don't want the controlled object to exit the users filed of view (leave the screen). I could hard code some boundaries; however, that probably will not be compatibly with every android phone since screen sizes vary.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL has nothing to do with bounding boxes. It's a graphics API operating on a vertex/polygon level. The applications that are using bounding boxes for some logic take them from a scenegraph-based spatial node management logic that is a part of graphics engine.